# Can an on-line retailer request ID and a photo of the credit card?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, scams

Recently while shopping on-line, a store sent me an E-mail to say in short, "The transaction failed to verify, please send us a copy of your ID and a photo of the credit card you used for the payment."  They suggest driver's license or passport.

While in-person, I know businesses will sometimes check ID and credit cards, but I've never seen such a request on-line.

I paid for this purchase using PayPal and not directly on the retailers website.

Is that a thing? Is that even safe?

Comment: Sounds fishy.   **Very** fishy.  This must be a small website from a retailer no one has heard of.

Comment: Yes, is a small shop of imported food.

Comment: As to whether the retailer **can** ask: of course they **can** ask...

Comment: My meaning is, is that safe to give them this information? I'd prefer to continue doing business with this company, as I can't find their products anywhere else in the USA, but I never saw such a practice before. Especially as I paid via PayPal. What risk can come to me to provide the ID and photo of a credit card? And is that a normal practice a business has to stop and verify the information?

Comment: Well, it might very well be legitimate... but don't take a chance.  Doing that is security Worst Practice; reply back telling them so, and that you'll have to buy from somewhere else until they enter the 21st century.

Comment: "Especially as I paid via PayPal".  LOL... tell them to try it again, or call PayPal.

Comment: @Freiheit Please re-read my question as I never asked where to buy imported food.

Comment: Did they say *why* the transaction failed?  I'd push back on that, and ask them to try again (after making sure your PayPal account is in good order with sufficient funds.)  Whatever the problem is, it should be possible to resolve within the scope of the payment method you've chosen to use.  Heck, maybe contact Paypal yourself and see if there's anything *they* can tell you about this transaction, or your account in general, that may be relevant.

Answer (score 8):

> What risk can come to me to provide the ID and photo of a credit card?

Identity theft.

> And is that a normal practice a business has to stop and verify the information?

When using PayPal??  **NO.**

Comment: They can request anything they want, that doesn't mean you have to give it to them. I'd find an alternative as the answer here shows what's really at risk.